How to set google_sigin in Flutter without Firebase and get ID token for backend server?
I am doing  a flutter project, in that I need to implement google signIn.

I installed the flutter dependency google_sign_in 6.2.1.
Create a project in the google cloud console and set the authScreen .
Get the clientId and Api key.
Add the Api key in AndroidManifest.xml like below:

 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.API_KEY"
    android:value="`Apikey`" />


Created a button for google signIn and add the signIn api like below:

const List<String> scopes = <String>[
  'email',
  'profile',
  'openid',
];

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: scopes,
  clientId:
      '`clientid`',
);

class SignUpEmailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpEmailScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUpEmailScreen> createState() => _SignUpEmailScreenState();
}

class _SignUpEmailScreenState extends State<SignUpEmailScreen> {
  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
  String? _idToken;

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      // Attempt silent sign-in to retrieve the idToken
      final GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
          await account?.authentication;

      if (googleAuth?.idToken != null) {
        // Successfully retrieved idToken
        setState(() {
          _idToken = googleAuth?.idToken;
        });
        print("ID Token: $_idToken");

        // Send the idToken to your Django backend
        // await _sendTokenToBackend(_idToken!);
      } else {
        print("ID Token is null. Make sure the Google account is authorized.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error retrieving ID Token silently: $error");
    }
  }


Now when Iam clicking the button  in terminal it displaying idToken is null.
I/flutter ( 7515): ID Token is null. Make sure the Google account is authorized.

Note: Is this beacuse any failure in setup or something like that
Iam expecting, when I clicking the button the consent screen should come and when we select the account I want to get the idToken of user
